# XCode 8.2 Crash on stop debug

Tags: debugging, crash, xcode8.2

I use XCode 8.2.1 to debug my app. Every time when click the stop debug button, The XCode will crash. This is the following crash info:

```
Process:               Xcode [1478]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               8.2.1 (11766.1)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-11766001000000000~5
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1478]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-01-06 16:24:45.369 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1212)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        A7D6D50D-A3D3-32EF-A3FC-160E5195E461


Time Awake Since Boot: 3000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

Does anyone has the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

There was a race condition bug in lldb that was fixed very recently - should show up in the next official tools release - that could cause debugger shutdown crashes. Without seeing the crashed thread though, it's hard to tell whether it was likely one of these crashes.